# How to break off an open websocket in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, websocket

I noticed that when I run my website remotely, I had a lot of problems due to a websocket closing after being interrupted. However it never happened locally before. So I was wondering if it is possible to close an active websocket in Google Chrome, without using the normal `WebSocket.Close()`. Because I really want it to be as if it lost connection, and not just `onClose`

Comment: You could unplug the network cable (or disconnect from WiFi) from the client to simulate a dropped webSocket connection.

Comment: Yeah but I was testing on localhost. So that won't do much

Comment: Well, so go run the client on a laptop and connect to the IP of your server.  You asked how to simulate a lost connection - I'm offering an idea how.  Chrome doesn't have the feature you're asking for.  You're going to have to cause it outside of Chrome.